# Split a List<string> on several(more than one) separators

Tags: c#, arrays, split

I know that it is possible to split a string array on more than one separators.

```
    {
        string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split(new[] { ',', ' ', '(', ')', ':', ';', '.', '?', '!'});
    }
```

But is it possible to split lists like arrays in the example?

Comment: Could you confirm what you mean by 'But is it possible to split lists like arrays in the example?' - in the example you are splitting a string into an array, do you just want to turn that into a list, are you trying to split a list?

Comment: I just wanted to know if I can split a list by more characters. I know how to do that when I use arrays,so I was interested in doing it when I use lists.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you mean by 'split a list' I'm afraid. If you wanted to turn a string into a list by splitting it on separators then that can be done. Let me know if the answer I've posted is of use though

Comment: Please define what you mean by "split a list".

Comment: You example does not "split a string array", it "splits a string into an array"

Comment: Yes, I mean split a string into a list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to split a string by more than one character, you can use a `Regex`. For the pattern expression, just put all the characters between brackets, like so:

```
var sampleInput = "John;Paul,George-Ringo";
var pattern = "[;,-]";
var split = Regex.Split(sampleInput, pattern);
foreach (var s in split)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Output:

```
John
Paul
George
Ringo
```

[Code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QGJuk6)

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments I'm not too sure if this is what you are after but if you do want to get a list of strings then try the following

```
List<String> input = Console.ReadLine().Split(  ',', ' ', '(', ')', ':', ';', '.', '?', '!').ToList();
```